# Cannot get onScroll function to fire only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, triggers, onscroll

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and found myself a little stuck on one seemingly super simple task with an `onScroll` function.

I have the following code (see below) which is working great. However, it currently fires every time the user scrolls up or down, returning to that particular vertical location on the page. I only want it to fire the first time it is scrolled to after a page load.

Please help!

Big respect and many thanks in advance!

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  $('#pro1').each(function () {
     var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop(),
     bottomOfWindow = topOfWindow + $(window).height();

     var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

     if(imagePos < bottomOfWindow-200 && imagePos >= topOfWindow-500){
       $(this).addClass('bigEntrance2'); 
     }else{
       $(this).removeClass('bigEntrance2');
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried $(window).scrollTo instead?

Comment: This works on user 'click', am I right? I don't want the user to have to click, just to scroll to a particular point on the page for the function to fire..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method. It is the same as the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, but only fires once per page load. So for your example, it would look like this:

```
$(window).one("scroll", function()
{
  # Scroll code here
});
```

Edit: I think I understand your question better. You want the code to check when you're in that scroll region, but only execute once. So to do that, you first should designate a custom event:

```
$(window).one("customEvent", function()
{
  $(this).addClass('bigEntrance2');
});
```

And then trigger that event when you want:

```
if(imagePos < bottomOfWindow-200 && imagePos >= topOfWindow-500)
{
  $(this).trigger("customEvent");
}
```

That way, the class 'bigEntrance2' is only applied once, which is what I think you want.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this one seems to work! But another issue - I have a scroll down (sting) style website. The function it only fires if I load the page at that particular scroll position, and doesn't fire if I load the page from the top of the string of pages?

Comment: It works now with this method, but only if the element is within the page view when the website is refreshed. Doesn't appear at all if website is loaded as normal from the top of the site. Weird! Any ideas?

Comment: Ryan - Thanks again, would I need to modify or remove any of the current code to integrate this? I assume just replacing the "if" section of the code would be sufficient, and adding the new custom code for the "bigEntrance2" function as a script in the header - am I right?

Comment: The custom event should still be inside a `$(document).ready()` block. But yes, I believe that replacing the if statement should be good. That being said, I'm still not sure what the `bigEntrance2` class does, so I'm not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a variable and use it as a flag. The first time the user scrolls once the page loads, you set it to true. After that, you check that variable to avoid doing always the same code.

```
var alreadyScrolled = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
     if(!alreadyScrolled) {
          $('#pro1').each(function () {
               var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop(),
               bottomOfWindow = topOfWindow + $(window).height();

               var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

               if(imagePos < bottomOfWindow-200 && imagePos >= topOfWindow-500){
                    $(this).addClass('bigEntrance2'); 
               }else{
                    $(this).removeClass('bigEntrance2');
               }
          });
          alreadyScrolled = true;
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Hmm..element doesn't load at all now. FYI the element is coded as 'visibility: hidden;' in CSS, so as to only appear via the function. Perhaps this is causing it to not appear?

Comment: That `visibility: hidden;` is associated with which CSS selector?

Comment: With the element I'm animating. It is hidden until called by this script.. It works now with either your method or Ryan's above, but only if the element is within the page view when the website is refreshed. Doesn't appear at all if website is loaded as normal from the top of the site. Weird! Any ideas?